# Matplotlib: add mean numbers to legends in brackets with some optional text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to display the average for each line on this chart adding it in brackets to the legend like this: "Type1 (20.5)". Right now I managed only to display legends as labeled ("Type1") or just the mean number ("20.5") by adding `df.mean()` to `ax.legend` OR rename legends as shown below which is not the best option if you have many of them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# create df
mydic = {'2017-9-11': {'Type1': 15, 'Type2': 47, 'Type3': 23}, '2017-9-12': {'Type1': 26, 'Type2': 39, 'Type3': 34}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydic, orient='index')

# plot it
fig = plt.figure()
ax = df.plot(figsize=(20, 10), linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0)
ax.set_xlabel("", fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel("Count", fontsize=16)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
# Put a legend to the right of the current axis
L = ax.legend(df.mean(), loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=18)
#rename lagends
L.get_texts()[0].set_text('Type1 (20.5 a week)')
plt.show()
```

Will appreciate your suggestions!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the legends strings as:

```
legend = ['%s (%.1f a week)' %(col_name, df[col_name].mean()) 
          for col_name in df.columns]
```

Comment: Can I add `/7` to get a daily number instead of weekly? I tried `df[col_name].mean()/7` but it doesn't work...

Comment: You should be able to do that... I tried `['%s (%.1f daily)' %(col_name, df[col_name].mean()/7) for col_name in df.columns]` and it worked for me

Comment: It works indeed. Not sure why my first attempt failed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this inside the plot function:
label =('Type 1' + '(' + str(df['Type 1'].mean()) + 'a week)')

Then repeat for each ax.